# UPDATE query isn't working when POST isset

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code that allows a user to reset their account from a url link

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "  ";
$password = " ";
$dbname = "   ";

$code = $_GET['code'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT com_code FROM user WHERE com_code = ".$_GET['code'];
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<form action='reset.php?code=" . $row["com_code"]. "' method='post'>Enter New Password: <input type='text' name='new_password' placeholder='New Password'><br><input type='submit' value='Submit'></form>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "  ";
$password = "  ";
$dbname = "    ";

  $pword = $_POST['new_password'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$sql1 = "UPDATE user SET password='$pword', com_code=NULL WHERE com_code = '$code'";
}
if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE) {
    echo "Password has been change successfully!";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
?>
```

I keep getting the error:

> Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query in
>   /home/u590953899/public_html/notify/reset.php on line 47 Error
>   updating record:

When you press the submit button, it is suppose to UPDATE the database where the com_code = the $GET url

**BUT**
What happens is that it only reloads the page, how do I fix this?

The link to it is: http://notify.bithumor.co/reset.php?code=123456789

Comment: Change your closing curly brace of isset condition inside your query code.

Comment: Can you `echo` your query and see what parameters you get ?

Comment: What do I put in the error query for it to be echoed out

Comment: Is this one script or two different scripts (for the form and the processing)?

Comment: If you use password form, do not use `input type='text'` use `input type='password'` instead.

Comment: @Hilardy you can just `echo $sql1;` after your query statement .

Comment: @alex the user must reset the password, so they must be able to see it

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to be inside isset like this :

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $sql1 = "UPDATE user SET password='$pword', com_code=NULL WHERE com_code = '$code'";

    if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE) {
        echo "Password has been change successfully!";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }
  }
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, please see notify.bithumor.co/reset.php?code=123456789

Comment: Error shows that you missed closing the curly braces '}' or have extra curly braces somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes in your code:

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $sql1 = "UPDATE user SET password='$pword', com_code IS NULL WHERE com_code = '$code'";

    if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE) {
        echo "Password has been change successfully!";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, please see notify.bithumor.co/reset.php?code=123456789

Answer (score 0):

We use `IS NULL` to check NULL in mysql

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
     $sql1 = "UPDATE user SET password='$pword', com_code IS NULL WHERE com_code = $code";
}
```

Read [NULL Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) in MYSQL

Comment: your forget to remove equal to in `com_code` before `IS NULL`.

Comment: Damm @IndrasinhBihola thanks for your update . Now correct my answer

Comment: @saty "Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query in /home/u590953899/public_html/notify/reset.php on line 47
Error updating record:"  So I basically receive the same error.

Comment: @saty   if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE) {

Comment: @saty then i get the error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'user' (T_STRING) in /home/u590953899/public_html/notify/reset.php on line 45"

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['Submit']` will never be set, when your submit button doesn't have `name="submit"`. Just having `type="submit"`, or `value="submit"`, or `id="submit"` will not do it. You need the `name` attribute for that.

Answer (score 0):

First check  that your input type has `name="Submit"`, if not add it.
After that **echo**  your query first,

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

  echo "UPDATE user SET password='$pword', com_code=NULL WHERE com_code = '$code'";

   $sql1 = "UPDATE user SET password='$pword', com_code=NULL WHERE com_code = '$code'";

  if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE) {
            echo "Password has been change successfully!";
   } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
        }

  }
```

And also all the code i.e. query executing and messages should be in the same if statement **( if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) )**.

I hope this works for you.